# Stopping Vbscript After Completion

Tags: vbscript

Im making a game called cube, when I noticed a problem. I looked at Task Manager Fr Any Extra Programs, when I noticed tons of vbsscript running. I tried searching around, but no scripts worked for me. Heres my code (It plays A Sound)

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Sound.URL = "Sounds\Hurt.mp3"
Sound.Controls.play
do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
wscript.sleep 100
loop
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
WScript.Quit 1
```

It still doesn't want to stop. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below example

```vb
With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
    .URL = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp\hit.wav"
    .controls.play
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until .playState = 1 Or .playState = 10
    ' .PlayState https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564085(v=vs.85).aspx
    ' "Stopped" (completed) or "Ready" (file not found)
End With
```